# Как общаться с методами?

Tags: php

Есть два метода public function One(){...} и public function Two(){...}

Оба они находятся в одном классе. в методе One() есть переменная $var, как в методе Two() использовать эту переменную?

Comment: добавьте в класс приватное свойство, а в методах обращайтесь к этому свойству - оно будет "глобальным" в контексте всего класса.

Comment: @Эдуард а в самом методе можно добавлять это свойство? типа public function One(){ public $var;  ...}

Comment: вроде бы можно, но лучше сделать его свойством класса во избежании​ ошибок в будущем. Просто объявите приватное свойство в классе, и оно будет доступно для любого метода этого класса.

Comment: спасибо. работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ClassName
{
    private $var;

    public function One()
    {
        $var = 'value';
        $this->var = $var; 
    }

    public function Two()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. 
Никак, их область видимости такая же как и в стандартных функциях, то есть только внутри метода. Для того что бы использовать переменную глобально, вам нужно либо явно передать ее во второй метод, либо объявить как свойство класса.

```html
Class testVariable{
 public static $a;

 public function method1(){
  self::$a = 'test' ;
 }

 public function method2(){
  echo self::$a; 
 }
}

testVariable::method1();
testVariable::method2();
```